# variable "i" in $("#show"+i) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to assign a function to several div ("show" + i) at the same time, each call will assign another div ("theDiv" + i), but the "+i" does not work.

```
$("#show"+i).click(function()
{
$("#theDiv"+i).show("normal");
});
```

If I remplace the "i" by its values(0,1,2...) the code is working. So why can I correct this?
this is the entire function:

```
function getInfoProduits1()
{

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(i<idProduits.length)
        {
            request.open("GET","http://patisserie-orient.fr/prestashop/prestashop/api/products/"+idProduits[i]+"?PHP_AUTH_USER="+PHP_AUTH_USER+"&ws_key="+ws_key,true);

            request.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if(request.readyState==4)
                    {
                        //alert("Status2 is  "+request.status);
                        if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0)
                        {
                            response1  = request.responseXML.documentElement;
                            nameProduits[i] = response1.getElementsByTagName('name')[0].getElementsByTagName('language')[0].firstChild.data;
                            //alert(nameProduits[i]);
                            priceProduits[i] = response1.getElementsByTagName('price')[0].firstChild.data+" €";
                            //alert(priceProduits[i]);
                            descriptionProduits[i] = response1.getElementsByTagName('description_short')[0].getElementsByTagName('language')[0].firstChild.data;
                            //alert(descriptionProduits[i]);
                            quantitieProduitsDisponible[i] = response1.getElementsByTagName('quantity')[0].firstChild.data;
                            //alert(quantitieProduitsDisponible[i]);

                            maDiv = document.createElement("div");
                            maDiv.id = 'id_de_la_div'+i;

                            malabel = document.createElement("div");
                            malabel1 = document.createElement("div");
                            mon_bouton1 = document.createElement("button");
                             maDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
                            mon_bouton1.id="show"+i;
                            maDiv2.id="theDiv"+i;
                            maDiv2.innerHTML="Détails:";
                            maDiv2.style.display="none";
                           //mon_bouton1.value='click';

                           $("#show"+i).click(function(){

            $("#theDiv"+i).show("normal");
            });
                         mon_bouton1.onclick='aff();';
                            malabel.innerHTML=nameProduits[i];
                            malabel1.innerHTML=priceProduits[i];
                            maDiv.innerHTML='<img src="Images/Icones/dollars.png" width="50" height="50" align="right">';
                            //maDiv.innerHTML='<button type="button" id="show" onclick="aff();">Détails</button> ';
                            maDiv.className="ui-bar ui-bar-e cadre";
                            document.getElementById("divbar").appendChild(maDiv);
                            document.getElementById('id_de_la_div'+i).appendChild(malabel);
                            document.getElementById('id_de_la_div'+i).appendChild(malabel1);
                            document.getElementById('id_de_la_div'+i).appendChild(mon_bouton1);
                            document.getElementById('id_de_la_div'+i).appendChild(maDiv2);
                            maDivvide = document.createElement("div");
                            maDivvide.innerHTML='<br>';
                            document.getElementById("divbar").appendChild(maDivvide);
                            i++;
                             getInfoProduits1();
                         }
                     }
                }

            request.send();

        }   
    else
        {
            return;
        }

}
```

Comment: How is i defined? Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: show more of the function please so we can validate the initialization of 'i'.

Comment: could you post the code that initializes and assigns values to `i`?

Comment: I'm willing to bet that instead of iterating over a bunch of numbered IDs that you could rework this to use classes instead. Either by getting the index of the "show" element on click or if "theDiv" has a consistent relationship (2nd nested div or whatever) using DOM traversal.

Comment: If I understand your updated question, you're trying to do a pattern match. But "+i" won't do this. "i" represents something that's supposed to be defined. For example, if before your functions you simply wrote `var i = 1;` then it would work for `#show1` and `#theDiv1`. Check out Nicola's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what you really mean but maybe this is what you need

```
//attach an event handler to all elements with an id that starts with "show"
$("[id^=show]").click(function(){
   //get only the number from the clicked id
   var i = this.id.replace("show", "");
  //show the relevant div
  $("#theDiv"+i).show("normal");
});
```

Comment: wonderful solution!! 7amdoulellah!! Thank you  @Nicola Peluchetti

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've fallen victim to one of the classic blunders, only slightly less famous than "Never go up against a Sicilian when death is on the line."

Variables used in a closure but defined outside of it are passed by reference - everyone shares 'i'.  So any time you call that function, you'll find that 'i' always equals the last value that was assigned to it, not the one that was set when you built the closure.  You fix this by running 'i' through a function to give you your closure.  Since the function is pass by value, you get the current value of 'i' bound to the closure.

```
function gimmeAFunctionToDoThatThingThatNeedsDoing(i) {
    return function() {
       // Move closure here
    };
}
```